# Can Smash online play with 3ds and Wii U together?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I have a 3ds xl and my buddy has a Wii U. We want to play smash together.

**Can we online play on different platforms together?**

I think the Nintendo website says yes but I cant tell for sure.

Also, for extra credit any major differences between the 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot play together across platform as the versions do not share stages. You may, however, transfer characters across platform.

See [**the wiki**](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Cross-platform_comparison_of_Super_Smash_Bros._4#Miscellaneous) for details on cross platform differences.

Comment: You can, however, if you are in the same room together, connect your 3DS as a controller to a game on the Wii U. But for online play over a distance, this is correct, there is no way.